# Acumatica - Outlook PlugIn Reply Action

Tags: acumatica

we are using Acumatica outlook plugin to create CASES and we are successful in achieving it.
As you know outlook plugin will automatically create a email activity when we create case. So sometimes we send reply from Outlook plugin and some times we send reply from Acumatica.

The issue is - When we send reply from outlook plugin we are unable to see email in "All Emails" screen, but if we are sending reply to same case from Acumatica we are able to see email in "All Emails" screen.
Can someone please suggest us, what we are missing here.

We are in 2019R2, without any customization published.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of reasons you may be running into this problem. Depending on how you have your setup, one reason could be because of the way you have your System Email Account set up. Check what email is sending as, it could be sending a centralized account. Also check what you default email is set on your account.

Also, are you using the Outgoing Tab? Or looking looking at the all records tab? It could be because of the status of your email. When sending through the Outlook plugin, double check the emails are sending, and double check the status of the activity. It could not be completing and being left as an open item.